# Problem with video background when I use CloudFlare for my SSL

Tags: ssl, cloudflare, firebase-hosting

Hi I have problem with the content of my website. Supposedly there should be a background video playing in my domain website but when I connected CloudFlare its empty. How to fix this?

**Before**
[image: With Video Background]

**After**
[image: Without Video Background]

I'm hosting via firebase and I bought the domain in Hosting, but there was a problem with security of the domain so I decided to add CloudFlare to my domain. After setting up CloudFlare I got that empty background. when I got my SSL ready (Secured).

Comment: Impossible to help without address, source code or any other info.

Comment: @Kinryu Can you give us your website URL with the problem?